# dispose in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

On the code below,
profileBloc is initialized in EditProfileScreenState's didChangeDependencies() method.

Should we be calling dispose method on EditProfileScreenState class to dispose the profileBloc ?

If so , how should the profileBloc method be disposed as ProfileBloc class extends Bloc class which doesn't have dispose method?

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => ProfileBloc(AuthRepo()),
      child: ProfileScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  EditProfileScreenState createState() => EditProfileScreenState();
}


class EditProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {

  ProfileBloc profileBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    profileBloc = BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    //profileBloc.dispose() cannot call as ProfileBloc class doesn't have dispose method
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
        },
        builder: (BuildContext context,ProfileState state) {
          return RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=>profileBloc.add(SaveProfile("name","email")));
        }
      ));
  }
}

class ProfileBloc extends Bloc<ProfileEvent, ProfileState> {

  AuthRepo authRepo;

  ProfileBloc(this.authRepo) : super(ProfileSaved());

  @override
  Stream<ProfileState> mapEventToState(ProfileEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SaveProfile) {
      //Actions
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the bloc is only disposed if you use BlocProvider to create it and the disposal happens when the BlocProvider is unmounted from the widget tree. Hope that helps

Answer (score 12):

While I was searching, I found the solution.

We don't need to initialize the profileBloc in didChangeDependencies().

We can access the add method directly from the BlocProvider using:

```
BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context).add(ProfileSaved())
```

We can remove following section from EditProfileScreenState class.

```
ProfileBloc profileBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    profileBloc = BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Moreover,
In ProfileBloc class we can use close method in case we need to cancel any streams.

```
@override
  Future<void> close() {
    //cancel streams
    super.close();
  }
```

Comment: You have forgotten to return "Future<void>" in your @override
  Future<void> close()

Comment: Must put "async"... Future<void> close() async { ...